# How can I move mouse by detected face and Eye using OpenCV and Python

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have managed to detect face and eyes by drawing cycles around them and it works fine with the help of Python tutorials [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) &  [Learn Opencv](http://www.learnopencv.com/delaunay-triangulation-and-voronoi-diagram-using-opencv-c-python/). Now I would like to make the mouse (Cursor) moves when Face moves and Eyes close/open to do mouse clicking. (PYTHON & OPENCV). Please help to give me more ideas on how I can make it works.
Thanks.

Check the codes below:

```
import cv2
import sys
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    Face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in Face:
         cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
         roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
         roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
         eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
         for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
             cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh), (0,255,0), 2)
   # Display the resulting frame
   cv2.imshow('Face and Eye Detected', img)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
#cv2.waitKey(0)
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in Windows environment, what you're looking for is the SetCursorPos method in the python win32api. Use:

```
import win32api
import cv2
import sys
...
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
    win32api.SetCursorPos((ex,ey))
    cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh), (0,255,0), 2)
```

This will set the cursor to the top-left vertex of the rectangle. If you wish to move the cursor to the center of the rect, use:

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((ex+ew/2,ey+eh/2))
```

Comment: Hello @SaranshKejriwal thank u for this it works fine, but it only moves the cursor on one angle, how to make it dynamic moves different angles when the Face moves in different position.

Comment: I do not understand. What do you mean by "moves the cursor on one angle" ? Since we're setting the cursor position based on the latest ex and ey, it should move wherever your eye goes

Comment: I mean when I run the program the cursor stays only at the top-left of the rectangle and doesn't move as eyes moves.

Comment: That is because you have performed "Eye detection", not "Eyeball detection". Ergo, the pointer will move when you move your whole face from one place to another.
If you wish to have the mouse follow your eyeball, extract the Eye ROI and perform colour thresholding to separate the pupil from the rest of the eye

Comment: Ooh..!!! I never knew that, let me try to search on Eyeball detection. If you have the solution / idea on how to detect eyeball, Please explain to me how while I'm trying to search on how to implement it. Thank you in advance @SaranshKejriwal

Comment: I managed to detect eyes pupils I tried to implement the function u gave me above win32api.SetCursorPos((ex+ew/2,ey+eh/2)) but, it doesn't work well. Any idea on how I can make mouse cursor click, move etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use **pyautogui** module for accessing the mouse and keyboard controls . The pyautogui is very simple to learn and the documentation is the best source no need to see any type of videos on that. Next you need to detect the white area of the eyes(corenia may be) using the contoursArea method available in open cv. When u see towards left the white area of right side of eye increases, and when the white area increases then the mouse must move left by function available in pyautogui that is pyautogui.moveRel(None,10)